Ceramic capacitor, service manual mentions 99% tolerance?
Sony part 1-102-050-00
Service manual states: 0.01uF - 99% - 500V
Ceramic cap looks like your average brown circle with no markings.
Used in CRT projector.
Basically no idea what tolerance I should get.
There is no 99%, so should I get a 'normal' 10% one or the 20/80 version?




(It will not be +-99 %, rather +100, -20.) Lower tolerance should always be acceptable,

What is the heading of the fifth column?

So a 10% would work without any issues?
I've not seen a +100 on mouser.
Header is called description, for all 3 specificatons.
But as you can see for the 'ELECTrolytics' it is obviously tolerance.

I agree with the +100/-20%, but I think with that tolerance range it might be a specialized capacitor as @qrk says. Can you show a picture with the surrounding circuitry?

Only two digits available in the system?

Pictures added.

There’s also a zero in that column, so I 2nd MrGerber’s comment and wish to see the column headings.

Never heard of a 99% tolerance! 
Other Sony service manuals don't give a tolerance for this part. I would assume any part meeting the voltage requirements would be fine, regardless of tolerance. Check if this is a special capacitor with a built in spark gap or has safety compliance logos.

Ok thanks. No logo's. No spark gap.
